# UITextField not able to access text

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift2

I am trying to code a simple adding app
This is what the code looks like

```
//number1Field is the name of my text field
let TextFieldInt = Int(number1Field.text)
```

It is giving me the error message "instance member 'text' cannot be used on type 'number1Field. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should put an exclamation mark just after 'text' to force unwrap it

```
let TextFieldInt = Int(number1Field.text!)
```

Comment: If the error still occurs you need to check the Outlet connection of number1Field

Comment: how do I check the outlet connection

Comment: Go to your storyboard and right click or in Mac (Two finger click) on your text field, then check its connection

Comment: what does it need to be connected to?

Comment: You should open your storyboard file and your ViewController.swift side by side, then control click on your TextField and drag the mouse over the ViewController.swift. Click connect. Then your code should work fine

Comment: It says instance member is not allowed in viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Because an UILabel's `text` property returns an Optional, you need to unwrap the value. And because `Int()` also returns an Optional, use something like this:

```
if let text = number1Field.text, let textFieldInt = Int(text) {
    print(textFieldInt)
}
```

Note that you could force unwrap the values with `!` instead of using the safe `if let` way but I don't recommend it because your app will crash in this case if the value is nil for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

`textField.text` method returns **optional value**. Try to force unwrapped with **!** or just put the question mark for safe like this;

```
let texts = Int(number1Field.text?)
```